# nuxt3 retrieve the variable from the URL

Tags: pinia, nuxt3

I am trying to get a global variable in Nuxt 3 that I can use on every page, but it doesn't seem to work. My goal is to retrieve the variable from the URL and save it as a global variable that can be accessed on every page

```
<script setup lang="ts">
// pages/test1.vue
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
const route = useRoute();
const idenger = route.query.idenger;

const countername = useState('countername', () => idenger);
</script>



// composables/state.ts

export const useCounter = () => useState<number>('counter', () => 0)

export const useCountername = (idenger: string) => {
  return useState('countername', () => idenger);
}
```